# Identifying worksheet index while Looping through worksheets, via getWorksheetIterator(), with PHPExcel

Tags: php, for-loop, phpexcel, worksheet

I'm using the PHPExcel library to read an Excel file with many worksheets and perform processing on it.  Now I have no problem looping through each worksheet.  However, I want to extract the index of each worksheet and print it out and I'm not sure how to do this.  Sure, I can make my own counter and be done with it.  But there must be a built-in method with the getWorksheetIterator() method, no?

That is, how do I extract the current worksheet iterator?

Thank you for any help.

Here is the documentation's looping example, for reference, slightly modified with the inclusion of the worksheetiterator method:

```
<?php
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("test.xlsx");
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$CurrentWorkSheetIndex = 0; 

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    echo 'WorkSheet' . $CurrentWorkSheetIndex++ . "\n";
    echo '<table>' . "\n";
    foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
      echo '<tr>' . "\n";

      $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
      $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // This loops all cells,
                                                         // even if it is not set.
                                                         // By default, only cells
                                                         // that are set will be
                                                         // iterated.
      foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        echo '<td>' . $cell->getValue() . '</td>' . "\n";
      }

      echo '</tr>' . "\n";
    }
    echo '</table>' . "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question.

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    echo 'Worksheet number - ', $objPHPExcel->getIndex($worksheet) , PHP_EOL;

    // rest of code above
}
```

Comment: Just as an FYI for those copy/pasta the object reference for the worksheet as defined in this answer changes to $worksheet, so replace     $objWorksheet 

with $worksheet where applicable

Answer (score 3):

The WorksheetIterator loops through each worksheet in turn, so the first is index 0, the second is index 1, the third is index 2, etc.

So either increment your $CurrentWorkSheetIndex for each loop of the iterator.

```
$CurrentWorkSheetIndex = 0;   

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $index = $CurrentWorkSheetIndex;
    ....
    $CurrentWorkSheetIndex++;
}
```

Or use the Iterator's key() method.

```
$wsIterator = $objPHPExcelR->getWorksheetIterator();
foreach($wsIterator as $worksheet) {
    $index = $wsIterator->key();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The second method, unfortunately, does not work.  Interestingly enough, $worksheet->key() gives a fatal error: undefined method PHPExcelWorksheet::key().  Yet, $wsIterator->key() gives a value (0 in every iteration).  Strange.  Why would the former produce an error and the latter does not?

Comment: It isn't the PHPExcel_Worksheet that has the key() method, it's the PHPExcel_WorksheetIterator. I've just tested it now, and it's returning 0, 1, 2, ... as expected

Comment: Thank you, Mark.  I'm afraid I don't understand.  Doesn't $wsIterator equal $worksheet inside the foreach closure?  So, shouldn't $worksheet->key() be the same as $wsIterator->key()?

Comment: No, the WorksheetIterator is a class that provides a series of methods allowing you to loop through each Worksheet object in turn (or rewind, or skip, or whatever) but it isn't a Worksheet object itself, just a set of methods that will work with foreach and return a worksheet object. Think of it like using a foreach() loop with an array... foreach($array as $element) {}... the $element is one entry in the $array, not the whole array